# Twitter Connect Phonegap Android

Tags: android, twitter, cordova

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Twitter) but i don't know where to put this code:

```
/*
 * Check if Twitter is installed
 *
 */
isTwitterAvailable(success, failure)
```

Sample use:

```
 window.plugins.twitter.isTwitterAvailable(
    function(bool){ 
        if(bool){
            // Do something

        } else {
            alert("Twitter is not available");
        }
    },
    function(){
        alert("We have a problem with the plugin");
    }
);

/*
 * Compose tweet and open the Twitter application
 */
composeTweet(success, failure, message) {
```

Sample use:

```
 window.plugins.twitter.composeTweet(
     function(){
     },
     function(){
        alert("We have a problem with the plugin");
     },
     "Base of the tweet"
);
```

and i also  followed [this tutorial](http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms).  everything is fine but when i run the project in android device it tells me "window.plugins.childBrowser that is undefined". I think that the problem is with ChildBrowser. the version of ChildBrowser that i use is 2.0.0 and the version of phonegap that i use for the 2 tutorials is 2.2.0.
I Only want a **twitter connect with phonegap** in **Android**

thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english